# Finding semidefiniteness of a matrix without constraints

Tags: matrices, permutations, positive-semidefinite

Hi Mathematics Community!

I am attempting to teach myself linear algebra and have stumbled across a topic that I can't seem to fully grasp and am hoping you can help. I understand positive and negative definite, but I don't understand the concept of (or how to decide) semidefiniteness of a matrix. I believe that you are supposed to take a permutation of the number of the rows in the matrix and then apply that somehow, but that is the extent of my knowledge.

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thank you.

PS. I also read somewhere that there is an eigenvalue method. However, it stated that there was a need for a symmetric matrix. What do I do if there is not a symmetric matrix?

Comment: No. you need to apply the same permutation on the rows **and on the columns**. Otherwise the matrix won't remain symmetric. If you need an example for a semidefinite but non definite matrix, take a diagonal matrix with zeros and positive values on the diagonal (and apply  permutation / orthogonal transformation if you like)

Comment: Are you saying you understand positive definiteness and negative definiteness, but not semidefiniteness?

Comment: Yes. I understand how to find both positive and negative definiteness as they are fairly trivial, but I don't understand how to find if it is positive/negative semidefinite.

Answer (score 0):

You may use Sylvester's criterion (look e.g. in wiki) for an $n\times n$ matrix $M$: if each determinant of every  $k\times k$ principal submatrix of $M$ is non-negative then so is $M$. Here, a $k\times k$ principal submatrix means choosing $k$ entries $I=\{i_1,\ldots, i_k\}$ among the rows and the same entries $I$ among the columns.

The permutations of rows as you mention doesn't quite make sense